# How to pick a value from a TextView into a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

this app is a simple phonebook ,this is the xml file for contact

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tvName" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAlignment="center" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

and contacts are contained in this listView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listPhone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />


</LinearLayout>
```

how can i pick up the value of the textfield called tvPhone when i click on his contact on the ListView ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the information for the TextView, you do as this :

```
String tvValue = tv.getText().toString();
```

If you loading the values from an adapter, and if you are storing the values in an array list, you will have something like this in the adapter side in the **getView()** method:

```
yourTextView.setText(mDetailsArrayList.get(position));
```

And to get the value of that, you will again get the value using:

```
getText().toString()
```

Depending on what's your values looks like, you may have values for int, float etc.

In this example, its a String value you are getting back.

Now, if you have a ListView and a textView on the same layout, you will simple get the value from the textView using the above method and add it to you arrayList for example and to Update the listView you will just notify the changes by using **notifyDataSetChanged()** method.

**EDIT:**

For an onClick event on a ListView, just use **onItemClickListener** as this :

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickListener);

public OnItemClickListener listItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

        String getText = yourArrayList.get(position).getTextFromTextViewMethod();



        }
    };
```

Good luck.. :)

Comment: first of all thank you ..but my real problem is how to do an onClick event on the contact of the ListView :)

Comment: Check the edit section. This is on how you can do on clicks events on ListView.